# How to mock @actions/github?

Tags: node.js, mocking, github-actions, building-github-actions, octokit

I have a GitHub action that is running on node. My node js file looks like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import * as core from '@actions/core';
import * as github from '@actions/github';
import { Octokit } from '@octokit/rest';

async function runAction() {

  const comments = await octokit.paginate(octokit.rest.issues.listComments, {
    1,
    "my_repo",
    1,
    per_page: 100,
  });
console.log(comments)
}
```

I'm trying to test this code - however I cannot seem to find a way of mocking @actions/github's `listComments` function.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Hi @Azeem. Seems like your code is importing `@actions/github` but it is not used in any of the lines. I guess you are omitting part of the code where you obtain octokit from `@actions/github`. Could you share the complete snippet of code so the community can help you better?

Comment: Hi @OscarDOM, I believe your comment was for the OP and not me. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to tag the author of the question: @Nespony